# C# check characters in clipboard when paste into textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, clipboard, paste

Are there some ways to check charater in clipboard only digit before paste into textbox C# (Both Ctrl+V and right click -> Paste), which not using MarkedTextbox.

Comment: The alternative way would be checking in Textbox text change event.

Comment: Do you care about drag'n'drop?

Comment: @DCODE: If i enter 1 digit from keyboard, then i paste some characters not digits. How can i prevent not paste those characters in text change event

Comment: check the new value. if condition failed the restore old value.
private string value;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // at this moment value is still old
    var oldValue = value;
    value = ((TextBox)sender).Text; // text1.Text

    // here you have oldValue and new value
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ~think~ you want a TextBox that can only accept digits?

If yes, then set the ES_NUMBER style on the TextBox via SetWindowLong():

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form2_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetNumbersOnlyTextBox(this.textBox1);
    }

    public const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
    public const int ES_NUMBER = 0x2000;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    public void SetNumbersOnlyTextBox(TextBox TB)
    {
        SetWindowLong(TB.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(TB.Handle, GWL_STYLE) | ES_NUMBER);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can Inherit from TextBox and set ES_NUMBER in CreateParams():

```
public class IntegerTextBox : TextBox
{

    private const int ES_NUMBER = 0x2000;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style = cp.Style | ES_NUMBER;
            return cp;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I hide the message when i paste character not digit?

Comment: With this approach, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Add rule in textbox text change to accept number only like:

```
        private string value;
             private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    // at this moment value is still old 
                    var oldValue = value;  
                    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only.");
                        textBox1.Text = oldvalue;
                    }
                    else{
                        value = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Fistly, I input 1 digit. Then, I paste characters not digits. The cursor is go to the first position of textbox, how can I fix it? @DCODE

Comment: I didn't totally get your point, can u explain in bit detail.. either you can do something like.. this.focus()

Comment: Firstly, I input '12' in textbox. Then I paste 'ab' after '12'. Now, the cursor go to the position before '1' character. @DCODE

Comment: Try this.Select(this.Text.Length, 0);  OR textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);

Comment: OR

txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;

OR

txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;

Comment: @DECODE: With your code, if I paste 'ab' after '1' and '2' , the cursor now go to after 2. I want the cursor still between '1' and '2' . How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: then do oldValue.Length

Comment: In this case, oldValue = '12', oldValue's length = 2. but I want cursor go to the postion after '1' and before '2'. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90486/discussion-between-dcode-and-do-thanh-tung).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there are anyways to check before pasting to TextBox, I would suggest subscribing to `KeyDown` and `MouseClick` events, and writing your own logic.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
     {
           // Your logic to read clipboard content and check length.;
     }     
}

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
     if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
     {
          // You logic goes here.
     }
}
```

You can get help from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to read/write clipboard content.

Comment: You really can't stop all clipboard/drag'n'drop interactions this way... Listening for  value change sound more appropriate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for suggestion, but `TextChange` event fires only after focus change, and the question is about performing action before paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want to only allow pastes that have digits only, then Inherit from TextBox and trap WM_PASTE, suppressing the message when desired:

```
public class DigitsOnlyOnPasteTextBox : TextBox
{

    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x302;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE && Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            int i;
            string txt = Clipboard.GetText();
            foreach(char c in txt)
            {
                if (!char.IsNumber(c))
                {
                    return;// suppress default behavior
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m); // allow normal processing of the message
    }

}
```